# Install PHP cURL on Amazon EC2 Micro Instance

Tags: php, curl, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I need to install PHP cURL on my Amazon EC2 Micro Instance.

I found a terminal code which should install PHP cURL through PuTTY.

```
sudo apt-get install php5-curl
```

But I get a lot of `403 Forbidden` errors.

I'm not good with Linux so I didn't really understand what those errors mean.

This is a screenshot of all the errors.

[image]

Comment: the 403's are from the source repository, you can specify another one.

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get update` before the install

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the 403 is from the source repository,

Try

```
sudo-apt-get update
```

before the install.  If that still doesn't fix it, add these lines to the /etc/apt/sources.list

```
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid main multiverse universe
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid-security main multiverse universe
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid-updates main multiverse universe
```

Answer (score 4):

Please try installing PHP curl with below command (Ubuntu)

```
sudo apt-get install php-curl
```

For Amazon Linux

```
sudo yum install php-curl
```

Comment: I am a bit confused by the Amazon Linux command. The versioned `php-common` package gives php-curl.  So to install php-curl (assuming php 7.2) you'd issue the command `sudo yum install php72-common`. The command in this answer gives the following output: `Package php72-common-7.2.13-1.7.amzn1.x86_64 already installed and latest version
`

Comment: I think we maybe commenting across each other Robin. The output indicates that `php-curl` comes from `php-common`. So the command `sudo yum install php-curl` should be `sudo yum install php72-common`. I did test this on a Amazon Linux box.